# Float:Left on divs not working as it should

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a series of DIV elements sit side by side. Howeever i am running into problems

HTML:

```
<div id="comic" class="comic">

        <div class="comic_panel">1</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">2</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">3</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">4</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">5</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">6</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">7</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">8</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">9</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">10</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">11</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">12</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">13</div>
        <div class="comic_panel">14</div>


        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#comic{
  height: 563px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  color:white;
    position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}


.comic_panel{

    width:1000px;
    height:563px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:orange;

}
```

However the result I get is simply the DIVS displaying under neath one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs are too wide to fit side by side in the container. Try giving them a width of `200px`:

```
.comic_panel{

    width:200px;
    height:563px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:orange;

}
```

If you want for a scroll bar to appear, use `white-space:nowrap;` on the container and `display:inline-block` on the children.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/h2StP/show

Comment: but shouldnt that make a scroll bar appear, which is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS to below,

```
.comic_panel{

    width:6%;
    height:563px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:orange;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

and they should fall side by side.

Basically child divs have same width as parent , so there is no room for them to sit side by side.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/k6RKy/)

Comment: but shouldnt that make a scroll bar appear, which is what i want

Comment: Give overflow-x:scroll; to  .comic_panel class

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that each inner divs (.comic_panel) are using all the width of the parent container (#comic). Then, the next div can only be place right below the previous one.

If you tune up the widths, you can have your result. 
For example, if you let the container div have any width, you would have all the inner divs side by side: http://jsfiddle.net/

```
body {
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 10000px;
}

#comic{
  height: 563px;
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  color:white;
  overflow: visible;
}


.comic_panel{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:63px;
    float:left;
    background:orange;

}​
```

To make the inner divs not wrap, you need to either set the width of the body element to a proper value (to make space for all the inner divs) via a hard-coded width css property (as in the fiddle, but not the best approach) or via javascript (a better approach).

This post explains other approaches, using tables: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/.

BTW, you may not need the `position: relative` that you put there to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole thing into a container div like this:

```
 <div id="container">
        <div id="comic" class="comic">
            <div class="comic_panel">1</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">2</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">3</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">4</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">5</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">6</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">7</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">8</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">9</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">10</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">11</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">12</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">13</div>
            <div class="comic_panel">14</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The container div should be the same size as your 'comic' div was before:

```
#container {
    height: 563px;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And the width of your 'comic' div should be 14000.

```
#comic{
  height: 563px;
  width: 14000px;
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}
```